# Show that the set $\Bbb R^2 \setminus \{-e_1, e_1\}$ is homotopy equivalent with $S(-e_1, 1) \cup S(e_1, 1)$.

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

> Show that the set $\Bbb R^2 \setminus \{-e_1, e_1\}$ is homotopy equivalent with $S(-e_1, 1) \cup S(e_1, 1)$.

So this is asking to show that $\Bbb R^2$ with two points missing is homotopy equivalent with the "figure eight". To show this I need to find maps $f : \Bbb R^2 \setminus \{-e_1, e_1\} \to S(-e_1, 1) \cup S(e_1, 1) $ and $g : S(-e_1, 1) \cup S(e_1, 1) \to \Bbb R^2 \setminus \{-e_1, e_1\}$ that satisfy $g \circ f \simeq id_{\Bbb R^2 \setminus \{-e_1, e_1\}}$ and $f \circ g \simeq id_{ S(-e_1, 1) \cup S(e_1, 1)}$.

I'm very confused on how to start constructing such maps. It seems as if I would need to map the whole plane to $S(-e_1, 1) \cup S(e_1, 1)$ somehow. Can I use the inclusion map here to map all points of the plane to $S(-e_1, 1) \cup S(e_1, 1)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that the circles are $\mathbb S^1+(0,1)$ and $\mathbb S^1+(0,-1)$. Put $c=(0,1)$ and consider
$$
    r_1\colon\{(x,y)\mid y\ge0\}\setminus\{c\}\to X
$$
defined as illustrated here

[image]

Do something similar for $y\le0$ and then define $r\colon\mathbb R^2\setminus\{c,-c\}\to X$.

It remains to be shown that $r$ is retraction by deformation. Consider
\begin{align*}
    H\colon\mathbb R^2\setminus\{c,-c\}\times[0,1]
        &\to\mathbb R^2\setminus\{c,-c\}\\
    ((x,y),\tau)&\mapsto(1-\tau)r(x,y) + \tau(x,y).
\end{align*}
To see that $H$ is well defined one needs to verify that equality in the equation
\begin{equation}
    \pm(0,1) = (1-\tau)r(x,y)+\tau(x,y)
\end{equation}
is never attained.

Comment: Why do you need to define two maps? Can't you just use the inner green one?

Comment: There would be discontinuity along the $x$ axis: points above it would go to the upper circle, while points below to the lower.

Comment: That's true thanks! So the retract would not be continuous. Another doubt I have. How do you define the retraction with for points with $x=0$ and $y\ge2$? Because the blue line would pass through $c$ and this cannot happen. Are you imposing that for these points you retract them with the green definition?

Comment: The blue line doesn't need to be included in the space. It is just a visualization for the way the map is defined.

Comment: I see, thanks! Last thing (sorry to bother, but you are really of help!): the reason why, instead, I cannot define the retraction just with the blue map is that all the points between the origin and $c$ (the removed point) could not be continuously moved to the point (0,2) of the circumference; hence we need the green map to send them to the origin, am I correct?

Comment: The blue map doesn't suffice because it can only be defined with continuity on the exterior of the circle. In other words, there is no way to define it inside the circle while having continuity at $(0,0)$. Points close to the $y$ axis would get projected near the north pole, so $(0,0)$ could not get fixed any extension of this map.

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

You want your map g to be the inclusion map. For f you want to use the gluing lemma, to find fitting subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$, which can be send to the figure eight (for example you can choose one of the subsets to be $B_1(-e_1)\backslash \{-e_1\}$, and find a map that gives a homotopy equivalence between $S(-e_1,1)\cong B_1(-e_1)\backslash S(-e_1,1)$

Comment: Why do I want $g$ to be the inclusion?

Comment: making g the inclusion, makes a lot of the computations easier. if f is a map that fixes $S(-e_1,1)\cup S(e_1,1)$, then $f\circ g=id$. and $g\circ f$ is just f, but with codomain $\mathbb{R}^2$ instead, since g it is just the inclusion into a larger codomain.