# Double punctured plane homotopic to double torus/figure eight on the plane

Tags: general-topology, analysis, homotopy-theory

> Let $ A=S(-e_1,1) \cup S(e_1, 1)$ denote the figure eight on the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. Show that $S(-e_1,1) \cup S(e_1, 1)$ is homotopically equivalent with the double punctured plane $B=\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus\{-e_1, e_1\}$.

I found this question here unanswered and not sure if the maps I've defined would work. If I let $f : A \to B, f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{x}{\|x\|} +(1,0), x > 0 \\ -\frac{x}{\|x\|} -(1,0), x < 0 \end{cases}$ and $g : B \to A, g(x) = x$. So $f$ takes  points from the positive part of $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus\{-e_1, e_1\}$ and maps them to the circle $S(e_1,1)$ and similarly points from the negative part of $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus\{-e_1, e_1\}$ are mapped to $S(-e_1,1)$. I'm not sure how to verify that these satisfy the homotopo equivalence?

Comment: What does your map do to the $y$-axis?

Comment: What do you mean by "positive/negative part of $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{-e_1,e_1\}$"? Since $\mathbb{R}^2 \cong \mathbb{C}$, there is no order on this set.

Comment: Meant $x > 0$ and $x < 0$. @jasnee

Comment: Your maps are ill-defined. First, you say that $f : A \to B$, but then in the sentence below you say "$f$ takes points from the positive part of $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{-e_1,e_1\}$ and maps them to the circle $S(e_1,1)$". Also, you can't have $g(x)=x$, because $g((0,1)) = (0,1)$, but $(0,1) \notin A$.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4187875/show-that-the-set-bbb-r2-setminus-e-1-e-1-is-homotopy-equivalent-with?rq=1) answer your question?